# Orchard - Add an additional shape name (i.e. an alternate) for the main List shape

Tags: razor, orchardcms

## Introduce the Problem

I would like to profoundly modify the layout of the **Orchard CMS Tags list**.

Here is an [example page](http://orchard-list.azurewebsites.net/Tags/hipster) with Shape Tracing enabled.

The only alternate that it suggests for the List shape is `~/Themes/TheThemeMachine/Views/List.cshtml`, because the page is rendering the default List shape. I would like to have other alternates that are specific to the page.

After reading [Orchard list customization](http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2011/05/23/orchard-list-customization-first-item-template.aspx), I have been able to implement the default List.cshtml in razor. What I would like to do, though, is to add another alternate, such as `~/Themes/TheThemeMachine/Views/Parts.Tags.List.cshtml` instead of implementing the default List.cshtml template.

The problem seems to be that the page is rendering the generic `List` shape.

In contrast, the [blog post list](http://orchard-list.azurewebsites.net) page is rendering a `Parts_Blogs_BlogPost_List` shape, which means that a `~/Themes/TheThemeMachine/Views/Parts.Blogs.BlogPost.List.cshtml` is available.

## Search and Research

All quotes below are from the [Orchard list customization](http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2011/05/23/orchard-list-customization-first-item-template.aspx) blog post, which explains how to add a list *item* alternate (whereas I would like to add a list alternate).

> What we really want is an alternate template... aptly called Shape
>   Alternates... [so] enable Shape Tracing... and select a post in the list...
>   [you will see that] we already have some possible alternates.

My [example page](http://orchard-list.azurewebsites.net/Tags/hipster) also has some possible alternates for the List Content. Cool.

> we need to somehow get into list rendering... [t]he default is defined
>   in code... [which] can be override by a new [cshtml] template in our
>   theme.

Okay. That makes sense. We can override the list rendering.

> As Shape Tracing can show, we can override the list rendering for a
>   blog by creating a Parts.Blog.BlogPost.List.cshtml template.

This works for alog but not for the blog **Tag** page ([example page](http://orchard-list.azurewebsites.net/Tags/hipster)). You see, the blog displays a **Parts_Blogs_BlogPost_List shape and suggests an appropriate alternate but the blog tags page displays the default List shape with no alternates other than List.cshtml.

**Blog Page** with alternates galore
[image]

**Blog Tags Page** with one alternate List.cshtml
[image]

So, I created a **List.cshtml not a Parts.Blog.BlogPost.List.cshtml** template, and save it in my theme's Views directory. (One problem here is that, once we get it working, we will b overriding the default List rendering.)

[image]

Then I add the Razor code (copy and pasted from Bertrand's post) to override the default rendering for Lists. **When I refresh the site, the browser renders a blank page.** It isn't working. Here's the code:

**This Does NOT Work in List.cshtml**

```
@using Orchard.DisplayManagement.Shapes;
@{
    var list = Model.ContentItems;
    var items = list.Items;
    var count = items.Count;
    var listTag = Tag(list, "ul");
    listTag.AddCssClass("content-items");
    listTag.AddCssClass("blog-posts");
    var index = 0;
}
@listTag.StartElement
    @foreach (var item in items) {
        var itemTag = Tag(item, "li");
        if (index == 0) {
            itemTag.AddCssClass("first");
        }
        else if (index == count - 1) {
            itemTag.AddCssClass("last");
        }
        @itemTag.StartElement
        @Display(item)
        @itemTag.EndElement
        ++index;
    }
@listTag.EndElement
```

As a trouble shooting step, I replace the List.cshtml with `<p>Hello world.</p>`. Orchard renders the markup as expected. So, something is incompatible between the Razor code from Bertrand's blog and the Tags List.

[image]

To find out what exactly is incompatible, I try Betrand's code one line at time to see where it breaks (yup, VS would be better than WM here). At each change, I restart WebMatrix and view the results. This is the minimal code that breaks it.

**The Culprit**

```
@using Orchard.DisplayManagement.Shapes;
@{
    var list = Model.ContentItems;
    var items = list.Items;
}
```

`list.Items` isn't appropriate here. So I comment it out again and run the `<p>Hello World</p>` version again. Also, Shape Tracing reveals that on my Tags/tagname page, the Content Zone is now rendering the List twice. Is that normal?

[image]

As another step, I replace `Model.ContentItems` just with `Model`. **It works**. It seems that, to override the List.cshtml template, we cannot use the ContentItems property of Model. Here is the new, working code:

**This Does Work in List.cshtml**

```
@using Orchard.DisplayManagement.Shapes;
@{    
    //var list = Model.ContentItems; 
    //var items = list.Items;   

    var items = Model.Items; 
    var count = items.Count;

    //var listTag = Tag(list, "ul"); 

    var listTag = Tag(Model, "ul");    
    listTag.AddCssClass("content-items");
    listTag.AddCssClass("blog-posts");
    var index = 0;
}
@listTag.StartElement
    @foreach (var item in items) {
        var itemTag = Tag(item, "li");
        if (index == 0) {
            itemTag.AddCssClass("first");
        }
        else if (index == count - 1) {
            itemTag.AddCssClass("last");
        }
        @itemTag.StartElement
        @Display(item)
        @itemTag.EndElement
        ++index;
    }
@listTag.EndElement
```

Onward through the article.

> So far so good, we have effectively taken over the rendering of the
>   list, but the actual HTML [will] be... identical to what we had before
>   [except for] the implementation.

Okay. I'm following. We want to modify the rendering not just re-implement it.

> Alternates are a collection of strings that describe additional shape
>   names for the current shape... in the Metadata.Alternates property of any shape.

Gotcha. Now, why doesn't the Tags/tagname page show an alternate other than just List.cshtml for the rendering of the List shape?

> All we need to do is add to this list [of alternates]... [and make sure] to respect the lifecycle...

Great. Maybe we can we add another alternate for the List shape on the Tags/tagname page. But, doing that is different from what Betrand is explaining. **While Betrand's blog post is excellent, it is explaining how to add an alternate for an item, whereas I would like to add an alternate for the list**.

The List.cshtml template is where I would add an alternate for a List Item as follows:

```
ShapeMetadata metadata = item.Metadata;
string alternate = metadata.Type + "_" +
        metadata.DisplayType + "__" +
        item.ContentItem.ContentType +
        "_First";
metadata.OnDisplaying(ctx => {
    metadata.Alternates.Add(alternate);
});
```

So that...

> [t]he list of alternates from Shape Tracing now contains a new item.

**Where and how, though, would I add an alternate for the List shape?** Bertrand has recommended to check out the [Shape Table Providers](http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2011/01/10/orchard-shapeshifting.aspx) blog post for this. The quotes below are from that post.

> But what if you want to change another shape template for specific
>   pages, for example the main Content shape on the home page?

This looks like a fit, because my example is the main List shape on the tags page. To do this we...

> ... handle an event that is triggered every time a shape named "Content"
>   [in our case "List"] is about to be displayed. [It] is implemented in a shape table provider which is where you do all shape related site-wide operations.

Great! Here is my implementation for adding another template for the main List shape.

**TheThemeMachine > ListShapeProvider.cs**

```
namespace Themes.TheThemeMachine
{
    using Orchard.DisplayManagement.Descriptors;
    public class ListShapeProvider : IShapeTableProvider
    {
        public void Discover(ShapeTableBuilder builder)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break(); // break not hit
            builder.Describe("List").OnDisplaying(displaying => {
                // do stuff to the shape
                displaying.ShapeMetadata.Alternates.Add("Tags__List");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

The above builds and runs but does not hit the breakpoint nor add an alternate for the List shape on the /tags page. So I looked into the Orchard.Azure.MediaServices module and its `CloudVideoPlayerShape` which implements IShapeTableProvider. Its breakpoint does get hit. How is my code for `ListShapeProvider` fundamentally different than the code for the `CloudVideoPlayerShape`?

Also, I installed the **Orchard.Themes.CustomLayoutMachine.1.0.nupkg** as suggested in Bertrand's blog post. It unfortunately no longer contains an implementation of `IShapeTableProvider`.

I have also looked at [this szmyd post](http://www.szmyd.com.pl/blog/customizing-orchard-shapes), which does not explain where to put the IShapeTableProvider code.

Further, I installed the Contoso theme from the Orchard Gallery. It works and builds after adding a reference to `Microsoft.CSharp.` It also includes an implementation of the IShapeTableProvider. Hooray! Comparing its `ContentShapeProvider` with my `ListShapeProvider` reveals a subtle but important difference:

**Contoso.csproj**

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Code\ContentShapeProvider.cs" />
</ItemGroup>
```

My implementation didn't include the .cs file in the compilation, because my theme has neither a .csproj nor a App_Code folder. So, I recreated my theme with the following code generation:

```
orchard.exe
feature enable Orchard.CodeGeneration
codegen theme My.FirstTheme /CreateProject:true
theme enable My.FirstTheme
feature enable Orchard.DesignerTools
```

When adding the ListShapeProvider.cs file, Visual Studio automatically added a ItemGroup/Compile entry for the file, which included the code in compilation. Hooray!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### These two posts will help.

- [Shape Shifting](http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2011/01/10/orchard-shapeshifting.aspx)
- [List Customization](http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2011/05/23/orchard-list-customization-first-item-template.aspx)

### Here are steps of my own minimum solution.

Download and unzip [Orchard.Source.1.8.zip](http://orchard.codeplex.com/releases/view/115750).

Open "\Downloads\Orchard.Source.1.8\src\Orchard.sln" in Visual Studio.

Build the solution to create [orchard.exe](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Using-the-command-line-interface).

Generate a new theme with [orchard.exe](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Using-the-command-line-interface). Use **CreateProject:true** because you will need a csproj to include your .cs file.

```
orchard.exe
setup /SiteName:SITE /AdminUsername:ME /AdminPassword:PWD /DatabaseProvider:SqlCe
feature enable Orchard.CodeGeneration
codegen theme My.FirstTheme /CreateProject:true
theme enable My.FirstTheme
```

In VS, add a **ListShapeProvier.cs** file to the root (or any folder) in your theme.

[image: ListShapeProvier]

Add the following code to ListShapeProvider.cs.

```
namespace My.FirstTheme
{
    using Orchard.DisplayManagement.Descriptors;
    public class ListShapeProvider : IShapeTableProvider
    {
        public void Discover(ShapeTableBuilder builder)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
            // implementation here
        }
    }
}
```

Build the solution.

Run Orchard.Web.

Visual Studio will break at `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break().` If it doesn't, go to the Orchard Dashboard and make My.FirstTheme the Current Theme.

Now read [Shape Shifting](http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2011/01/10/orchard-shapeshifting.aspx) to implement `public void Discover(ShapeTableBuilder builder)`.

Answer (score 1):

This post should give you a full response: http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2011/05/23/orchard-list-customization-first-item-template.aspx

Comment: The post gives an answer for how to override `Parts.Blogs.BlogPost.List.cshtml`. That is not what I want to do, though. What I would like, instead, is to override `List.cshtml`.

Comment: Done. I am updating my question with a point-by-point analysis.

Comment: I have also changed the title to reflect the need to add an alternate to the list of alternates that are available on the page.

Comment: To add alternates to the list itself (or to any shape for that matter), you can use a shape table provider. See http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2011/01/10/orchard-shapeshifting.aspx for details. Also, you should do yourself a favor and stop using WebMatrix. Visual Studio will enable you to attach a debugger and view what's under your model without all the tinkering with the code one line at a time.

Comment: Thank you. I will look into the Shape Table Provider. It's funny you mention WebMatrix vs Visual Studio. Despite five years of experience with VS, I use WM for lightweight work. I will fire up VS and explore the Model.

Comment: Reading your posts helped find the solution. The final challenge was adding a .cs file to the theme.

Comment: No, that's fine. I appreciate the effort.